# Can I change today's date for the purposes of testing?

Tags: python

I have a function that carries out some logic based on today's date:

```
def do_work()
  todays_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
  #do something based on todays_date
```

I want to write some unit tests that verify that this function does what it is supposed to on given days of the year. Is there any way that I can change the value that get's stored in `todays_date` without changing the function?

I suspect not, but just thought I'd ask.

Comment: just found https://github.com/spulec/freezegun which looks like it will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mock module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) can come in handy in this case. The documentation has [an example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking) on how to partially-mock a fixed date.

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> with patch('mymodule.date') as mock_date:
...     mock_date.today.return_value = date(2010, 10, 8)
...     mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kw: date(*args, **kw)
...
...     assert mymodule.date.today() == date(2010, 10, 8)
...     assert mymodule.date(2009, 6, 8) == date(2009, 6, 8)
...
```

Comment: great thanks, will give it a go.

Comment: Just fixed the link to the example (it was pointing to the wrong place).

Comment: I couldn't get it working with the example that you linked to however it contained a further link to https://williambert.online/2011/07/how-to-unit-testing-in-django-with-mocking-and-patching/ which did work for me. Thank you.